# Complex Least Squares Derivation

Tags: least-squares

Considering the Complex Least Squares Problem, one can write the cost function for estimating **H** (where **Y** = **XH** + **Z**) as:

*Reference*: Mimo-OFDM Wireless Communications with MATLAB book (page 190)

$J(\boldsymbol H) = ||\boldsymbol Y - \boldsymbol X \boldsymbol H ||^2 = (\boldsymbol Y - \boldsymbol X \boldsymbol H)^H(\boldsymbol Y - \boldsymbol X \boldsymbol H) = \boldsymbol Y^H \boldsymbol Y - \boldsymbol Y^H \boldsymbol X \boldsymbol H - \boldsymbol H^H \boldsymbol X^H \boldsymbol Y + \boldsymbol H^H \boldsymbol X^H \boldsymbol X \boldsymbol H$

Calculating the derivative of the above function with respect to **H** gives:

$\frac{\partial J( \boldsymbol H)}{\partial \boldsymbol H} = -2(\boldsymbol X^H \boldsymbol Y)^* + 2(\boldsymbol X^H \boldsymbol X \boldsymbol H)^*$

How do I get to the expression above? Do I need to use some properties? I am trying to do that deriving each term separately.